# Make div visible when viewed on mobile device, hidden when not

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so that when users view my site on a mobile device (a max-width of 414px), a specific div (mobile-articles) is visible. However when viewed on desktop, the view should be hidden. I've tried the below, however my div doesn't seem to be visible on a mobile device (though it is hidden on desktop). How can I fix this? See code below:

**Test.html**

```
    <style>

        .mobile-articles {

            visibility:hidden;
            display: none;
        }


    @media (max-width: 414px) and (min-width: 367px) {

      @viewport {
        width: device-width;
      }


    }

    @media screen and (max-width : 414px) {

        .mobile-articles {

            visibility:visible;
            display: block;

        }

    }   
    </style>

<body>

<div class="mobile-articles"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Did you declare the viewport in the `<head>`? Something like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: @Logiwan992 The viewport is declared inside of <style></style>?

Comment: I edited my comment. You need `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the html

Comment: it's working fine in that fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/taltmann/m8d35g9n/

Comment: @ThomasAltmann Hmmm you're right - why does it work there but not on my actual page??

Comment: maybe some more css hides it again? or probably some JS even? I can't tell since I don't know the actual page

Answer (score 2):

In order to use media queries in your css you need to include a meta tag inside `<head>` to set the device-width to the width.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Comment: When I put the device-width/viewport inside of my header like this, it completely shrinks & distorts my layout? That said, the div does appear?

Comment: You have to style your page for a mobile view. Not just one element.

Comment: That doesn't make sense? When I place viewport inside of my style tag it scales my entire layout properly - the only issue is that my div doesn't appear when set to visible. But when I place the viewport in <head> as you did above, the layout distorts but the div disappears.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the layout distorting. You will have to provide a jsfiddle or codepen for further investigation. The `<meta>` tag should only be inside `<head>`, not `<style>`.

Comment: Strange - see: https://jsfiddle.net/taltmann/m8d35g9n/ My code seems to work there? But it doesn't when I display it on my actual page?

Comment: Maybe try removing the `, initial-scale=1` from my `<meta>` tag. Perhaps that is causing your layout distortion?

Comment: I did - still distorts things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133681/discussion-between-logiwan992-and-brittany).

Answer (score 2):

**CSS Solution:**

```
.mobile-articles {
  display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:780px) {
  .mobile-articles {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

**JS Solution:**

```
  <script>
  if (window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)||
    window.navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
   document.getElementsByClassName('mobile-articles')[0].style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
  document.getElementsByClassName('mobile-articles')[0].style.display = 'none';
  } 
  </script>
```

If still dont working I recomend you to delete the this code in CSS stylesheet

```
   @media (max-width: 414px) and (min-width: 367px) {

      @viewport {
        width: device-width;
      }


    }
```

Anyway , if you want to simplify code , you could use Bootstrap, materialize , or any other framework as big as those

Comment: Super strange - the CSS solution works in my browser when I shrink it down to lower than 500px wide. However on my mobile device there is no change.

Comment: Correction: max-device-width corrects this issue on the device (max-width alone doesn't do it). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use bootstrap and its visibility classes which is for exactly you are trying to do.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_responsive_utilities.htm

For your code; i think you can try specifying window size for large screens too. I mean first style for mobile articles class should be in a media query too.

Answer (score 0):

if you use bootstrap you can do:

```
<div class="d-sm-block d-lg-none" >
```